# fadeIn Navigation on mousemove() - fadeOut after certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousemove

I have a `#pagination` on my site which is by default set to `display:none`

When moving the mouse on my entire document I want to fade them in and fade them out after a certain time once the mousemovement stopped. I have absolutely no clue what's the best way to do this. Any ideas on that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(document).on('mousemove', 'body', function() {
        $('#pagination').fadeIn('fast');
        //once the mousemovement stopped I want a 3sec counter till it fades out agian
    });
    
});
```

Once the mousemovement stopped I'd like to have a short delay in it before the `#pagination' fades out again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you'd want to make sure the user stops moving their mouse before fading our your #pagination, you'd need to set a simple timer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var c, p = $('#pagination');
    $(document).on('mousemove',function() {        
       p.fadeIn('medium');
       clearTimeout(c);
       c= setTimeout(function(){
           p.fadeOut('medium');
       }, 600);
    });

});​
```

Whenever the user stops moving their mouse, the `#pagination` fades out. When they start moving it again, `#pagination` fades in. You could easily modify it if you don't want it to fade back in.

See the live example at: http://jsfiddle.net/akVkT/2/

Comment: +1 but No need for `var t`, I took the liberty to modify your demo and code

Comment: I also removed `var p` from the mousemove iterations. No need to be there.

Comment: quite interesting that in this exact case `fadeTo(time, opacity)` cannot be used, even with `.stop()` it does not work. Looks like `.fadeIn/Out` are not subject to animation bubbling. Like in this example: http://jsbin.com/ohekoy/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('mouseout', '#pagination', function() {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('fast');
    });

});
```

This is for 5 sec. after 5 sec it will fadeout

Comment: Ah, thank you. However I made a mistake in my code above. I don't want the mousemove event bound to `#pagination` but to the entire document. I updated my question, sorry fo that. So once the mouse is moved on the website the `#pagination` should fade in. If the mouse-movement stops I want a delay of a few seconds till the `#pagination` fades out again.